# SP 2010 Search API - How to get snippet from document

Tags: 2010, search

We are currently using SP 2010 and the Search API (not FAST)
(Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.FullTextSqlQuery)

I have read the below properties without any problem

```
SELECT Title, Url, Description, FileExtension, FileName, IsDocument FROM SCOPE() WHERE ...
```

But when I get a search hit on a document I want the text where my search phrase appears. I have seen screen shots from SP 2010 (search center/web part), 
where it appears below the link to the document.

Comment: I'd have to check, but I think you are looking for the "Hit Highlighted Summary". If you have trouble finding it I can look later today.